# Can't Modify Dictionary Value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've been using this code to try and modify some data that would be written to a file, but no matter what I do, even directly assigning it null bytes, it won't change. I am trying to access the dictionary entry from a seperate class than the one it was generated in.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(
    pio.GetBuffer(), 
    0, 
    Wat.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data, 
    0,     
    Wat.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length);

Buffer.BlockCopy(
    pio.GetBuffer(), 
    Wat.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length, 
    Wat.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFE].Data, 
    0, 
    Wat.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFE].Data.Length);
```

Here is the variable in the class, as well as how I initialized the dictionary:

```
public class SettingEntry
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

­
    public Dictionary SettingEntryList = new Dictionary();

When writing the data to the file, I go through each key like so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SettingEntry> SE in SettingEntryList)
{
    pio.WriteBytes(SE.Value.Data);
}
```

I have gone through and debugged. Once I was sure the key existed and all, I used this code, in which when I ran, the application stayed in the loop until I exited:

```
while (GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data != new byte[GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length])
GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data = new byte[GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length];
```

Comment: pio is my class for reading and writing files. Basically, I start out with combining the two dictionary entry datas(0x63E83FFF & 0x63E83FFE) into one for easier use and smaller code. Then, I modify the data, and now I want to separate the bytes and write the new array to the dictionary values with the code I posted.

Comment: Call me picky, I find local-scope variables starting with caps are unexpected and confusing; I'd expect `foreach (var se in SettingEntryList)`. "SE" should stand for "Stack Exchange" :)

Comment: Your call semantics are really kind of strange and my guess is that something in how WriteBytes works is wrong.  What happens if you change it to work so pio returns an array of byte[] by something like GetBytes() and you do SE.Value.Data = pio.GetBytes().  That would be more logical to me.  Also agree with retailcoder about the style, but that's minor

Comment: I misunderstood which direction you were going with this.  Sorry I thought you were trying to write to the dictionary.

Comment: My bad, SE standed for Setting Entry. The endian IO(pio) is working 100% fine, since if I replace pio.WriteBytes(SE.Value.Data) with pio.WriteBytes(new byte[SE.Value.Data.Length]), it writes the null bytes. I'm just trying to edit the data and write it back. The problem is that the variable won't change, and I've tested it by directly assigning it null bytes(GPD.SettingEntryList[blah].Data = new byte[someNum]) and compared it with the data beforehand, and it returned that they were the same, meaning the variable won't change.

Comment: How are you trying to change the dictionary? There doesn't seem to be any code in the question that does that.

Comment: I am using Buffer.BlockCopy to separate the new array into the two dictionary values.

Comment: That should work just fine. Are you sure you're not getting an exception? Like key not found exception, or similar? First off, it's not the dictionary you're modifying here, it's the objects inside the dictionary, crucial difference. Besides, a dictionary is not read-only so you sure you can modify it (but that's not what you're doing). My guess is that 1) the dictionary does not in fact have any SettingEntry object for the two keys, or that 2) the lengths of the arrays inside the two objects are of incorrect length. Can you show more code around the BlockCopy code? Like the entire method?

Comment: I am sure. I have gone through and debugged. Once I was sure the key existed and all, I used this code, in which when I ran, the application stayed in the loop until I exited:                           while (GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data != new byte[GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length])
                GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data = new byte[GPD.SettingEntryList[0x63E83FFF].Data.Length];

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary is not read only.

You are writing the bytes not to the dictionary but to the Data property inside a value in the dictionary.

If you really want to override a dictionary entry use -

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SettingEntry> entry in SettingEntryList)
{
    var val = new SettingsEntry() { Data = new DataType() };
    pio.WriteBytes(val.Data);
    entry.Value = val;
}
```

Comment: Hm. So it would be impossible to just overwrite the byte array value? Because for this question, I shortened the class for less to work with, so there are other variables. If so, I guess I will use this.

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the class, but if the byte array value  has a setter it's possible, if it doesn't, you shouldn't do it.. You can set a private value using Reflection but there's a reason they don't let you set the value.

Comment: Feel free to decline, but could it be possible you can use TeamViewer with me to view the two classes for a solution that more benefits just assigning the variable?